# Can Write-debug messages be transferred to Log file?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Write-verbose messages are not redirected to Out-File.

My advanced function fails without any trace so i would like to place debug messages. When the script is executed it will not run in console so i could not see the message .

If the messages can be transferred to log file then i can see it. Whether the Write-debug can pass the value to log files?

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Powershell v3+, you can redirect the debug stream to a text file:

Sample file: test.ps1

```
$debugPreference = "Continue"
Write-Output "Output msg"
Write-Debug "Debug msg"
```

From the powershell command line:

```
c:\temp\test.ps1 5>c:\debug.txt
```

c:\debug.txt then shows a single line "Debug msg"

The segment **5>c:\debug.txt** is a little obscure, so let's break it down. The "5" represents the debug stream, which is the 5th intrinsic Powershell stream as described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell.aspx) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx). The >c:\debug.txt then tells it to redirect all debug output to the file.

You can also play with 5>&1, which redirects the debug stream to the normal stdout.

If you're in Powershell v2, you can look at [this compiled module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Write-timestamped-output-4ff1565f) that provides good logging, or you can use a script-local function as described [here](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/making-debug-log) similar to this:

```
$DebuglogPreference = 'Continue'
function Write-DebugLog 
{
   param( [string]$message, [string]$filepath = 'c:\debug.txt' )

   if ($DebuglogPreference -eq 'Continue') 
   {
       $message | Out-File $filepath -append
   }
}

Write-DebugLog "Debug msg"
```

Comment: PowerShell allows stream redirection only to a file or to the success output stream. Redirection to any other stream (e.g. `5>&4`) will throw an error. Also, the question is tagged `powershell-v2`, which supports only success and error stream. Warning, verbose, and debug stream were introduced with PowerShell v3.

Comment: Removed reference to 5>&4 and added additional options for Powershell v2.